# What is Blob in Tesseract OCR

Tags: ocr, tesseract

I am learning Tesseract OCR and reading this [article](http://www.assistivetechnology.vcu.edu/wp-content/uploads/sites/1864/2013/09/pxc3882784.pdf) that is based on this [article](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/docs/blob/master/tesseracticdar2007.pdf). From first article:

> First  step  is  Adaptive  Thresholding, which converts the image into
>   binary images. Next step is connected  component  analysis which  is 
>   used  to  extract character outlines. This method is very useful
>   because it does the OCR of image with white text and black background.
>   Tesseract   was  probably  first to  provide  this  kind  of 
>   processing.  Then  after,  the  outlines  are  converted  into  Blobs.
>   Blobs  are  organized  into  text  lines,  and  the  lines  and 
>   regions  are  analyzed  for  some  fixed  area  or  equivalent  text 
>   size.

Could anyone explain what is Blob?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From https://tesseract-ocr.repairfaq.org/tess_glossary.html :

> Blob
>
> Isolated, small region of the scanned image. It's delineated by the outline. Tesseract 'juggles' the blobs to see if they can be split further into something that improved the confidence of recognition. Sometimes, blobs are 'combined' if that gives a better result. See pithsync.cpp, for example.

Answer (score 1):

Generally a blob (also called a Connected Component) is a connected piece (i.e. not broken) in a binary image. In other words, it's a solid element in a binary image.
Blob finders are a key step in any system that aims extracting/measuring data from digital images.